# Why can't I do std::map.begin() + 1?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, stl

I have a `std::map`, which I want to iterate over, starting at the second entry.

I can workaround this fine, but I'm confused about why the "obvious" syntax doesn't compile. The error message doesn't help, because it refers to `std::string`, which I'm not using here.

Here's some code

```
// Suppose I have some map ...
std::map<int, int> pSomeMap;

// This is fine ...
std::map<int, int>::const_iterator pIterOne = pSomeMap.begin();
++pIterOne;

// This doesn't compile ...
std::map<int, int>::const_iterator pIterTwo = pSomeMap.begin() + 1;
```

Visual Studio 2012 gives the following error on the above line:

```
error C2784: 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr> std::operator +
(_String_iterator<_Mystr>::difference_type,std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>)' :
could not deduce template argument for 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>' from 'int'
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Most bizarre error message ever?

Comment: @NathanOliver: If you're editing posts to move error messages from quotes to code blocks, may I suggest adding `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to disable syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`std::map<T>::iterator` is of the iterator-class *bidirectional iterator*. Those only have `++` and `--` operators. `+N` and `[]` is only available for *random access iterators* (which can be found in e.g. `std::vector<T>`).

The reason behind this is that adding `N` to a *random access iterator* is constant time (e.g. add `N*sizeof(T)` to a `T*`), whereas doing the same thing for a *bidirectional iterator* would require applying `++` `N` times.

What you can do though (if you have C++11) is:

```
std::map<int, int>::const_iterator pIterTwo = std::next(pSomeMap.begin(),1);
```

which does the right thing for all iterator types.

Comment: That's excellent - `std::next` looks a lot cleaner to me too. Thanks +1.

Comment: @RogerRowland Note that `std::next` is a C++11 addition. But if you don't have C++11, it is easy enough to implement your own `next` using `std::advance`. Or use `boost::next`.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks, I have VS2012 which is probably the nearest that MS will ever get to C++11! It compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 7):

`std::map` iterators are bidirectional, thus they provide only ++ and -- operators, but not `operator+`, even if it is +1.
You can use `std::advance` if you really need to simulate operator+, but that would result into sequence of increment being called for the iterator.

Comment: Why has it chosen to complain about string?

Comment: That's helpful, thanks, although like @doctorlove, I still don't understand the compiler error. I wonder what other compilers report.

Comment: @doctorlove Well it is better to ask msvc compiler developers. gcc gives all possible deductions. http://ideone.com/UUz5Xr

Comment: sidenote) std::advance modifies the iterator itself and returns nothing, whereas std::next returns a new iterator. (std::next is from C++11).