# Why I can't use `+1` in the iterator of `map` in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, iterator

I have a problem about the iterator using in `map`. I have a map with type of `map<int, vector<int> > vpmap;` I want to loop through the whole map. Then I use

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < vpmap.size(); i++) {
    {
        auto it = vpmap.begin();
        it++;
        /*code*/
    }
```

This is well. But when I replace the `it++` to `it=it+1`. The complier gives an error. I haven't get this error before when using `vector`. I would like to know the reason of it.

Comment: To iterate over the map you should use something like `for( auto const& [key, val] : vpmap )`

Comment: You can use `it = std::advance(it, 1)` instead of `it = it + 1` regardless of the iterator type. And you can use any number or variable instead of 1, even negative values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector::iterator` is a [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). It is required to support the operation `it + 1`.

On the other hand, `std::map::iterator` is a [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). It is not required to support `it + 1` but it is required to support `it++` as well as `it--`.

Relevant detail from [an answer to a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17484408/434551):

> The reason behind this is that adding `N` to a random access iterator is constant time (e.g. add `N*sizeof(T)` to a `T*`), whereas doing the same thing for a bidirectional iterator would require applying `++` `N` times.

Answer (score 5):

`it` is the iterator of [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), it's an [Bidirectional Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) and doesn't support `operator+`.

[RandomAccess Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) supports `operator+`, e.g. the iterator of `std::vector`, that's why you did not get this error with `std::vector`.